# I don't want to write driver.findelement(By.xpath("")) again and again

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi this is the code below: What I want to do is this build a function in which i just pass the value of XPath, so i don't have to write `driver.findElement(By.xpath(""))` again and again.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lead_source']")).sendKeys("Existing Customer");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='date_closed']")).sendKeys("08/07/2013");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sales_stage']")).sendKeys("Opportuntiy Qualification");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='opportunity_monthly_volume']")).sendKeys("10895");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='probability']")).sendKeys("90");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='opportunity_sales_rep']")).sendKeys("Sales Rep");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='opportunity_sales_regions']")).sendKeys("Northeast");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='opportunity_current_lab']")).sendKeys("Current lab");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(Payermixcss +"opportunity_medicare")).sendKeys("5");
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use By.id over By.xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use the [PageObject](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) pattern. You could do something like this:

```
public class MyFormPageObject {

    public MyFormPageObject enterLeadSource(String value) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("lead_source")).sendKeys(value);
        return this;
    }

    public MyFormPageObject enterDateClosed(String value) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("date_closed")).sendKeys(value);
        return this;
    }

    //...

}

// then in your test code
myFormPO.enterLeadSource("Existing Customer").enter("08/07/2013");
```

Note that as mentionned, you should use `By.id` if you have an identifier, because XPath is slower and not always well supported by all implementation of `WebDriver`.

Comment: I'm honestly not a fan of this. This is not worse but has no advantages at all. `findElement()` allows multiple overloads, while this one only takes in xpath. Someone may need more methods like `getElementByCssSelector` etc. The only advantage is fewer characters are used but this isn't solving the problem at the right direction. What OP really needs is a good design. The solution to this question should be using [PageObjects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), like Arran's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647760/16648629#16648629) (the PageObjects part).

Comment: Well this answers the question *I want to do is this build a function...*. But I agree, the best solution would be to use a PageObject pattern. Also with this pattern, you need to call the driver many times and then, a common method to wrap the call to `WebDriver` can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You convinced me. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @LaurentG You should post the Page Object answer separately; it's a bit confusing having two quite different solutions in the same answer - and I want to upvote one and not the other.

Comment: I first wanted to do this, but I could not delete my first answer since it was accepted.

Comment: I removed my first answer since I don't link it too. Devraj is free to not accept my answer anymore if he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

Extract a method to upper level and just pass the values as parameters

eg:

yourMethod(Path path) {

driver.findElement(By.xpath(path))

}

Comment: Still not able to do it , it would be help if you can elaborate a bit more. as I am newbee to this.

Comment: @Devraj Your problem is not related to Selenium, but to programming. First learn what is the goal of a method/function.

Comment: @LaurentG Agreed to you \m/

Answer (score 0):

As per your concern you can you use page object model and create the method and pass the variable to exact method.. I don't konw java but i know and concepts

```
private string variable= "Xpath value"
```

Pass this variable to method and it will interact with POM.. Before that u should know about POM. Then u can easily understand the concepts. Hope it will help full you...

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the amount of code you have to write, you could use a function like this:

```
private WebElement findElementByXpath(String xpath) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
}
```

The first line of your code would be:

```
findElementByXpath("//*[@id='lead_source']").sendKeys("Existing Customer");
```

It does not really reduce the length of the code but it only takes one CTRL + SPACE for autocompletion in Eclipse IDE.